# Running an executable that has been hidden using alternative data streams prompts me to select a default application

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, ntfs

Here is a screenshot of the commands I ran and the response I got:
[image: Image of the issue.]

In a way I'm trying to combine both the server.exe file and the game.exe file using ads(**alternative data streams**). Then calling on them later individually using a terminal, or having them execute in different orders using a script. There's nothing special about the files, they're placeholder names because this is happening with any executable I try it with.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden by ADS"? What, precisely, is the program you're trying to run, and what is game.exe.

Comment: Please avoid using acronyms unless they are a) exceptionally well known, or b) (and this is better) you've already defined them earlier in the question. Use the EDIT button to improve your question.

Comment: Executables are page files. Every program you open your total virtual memory goes up. That means they are **not** read as streams but are memory mapped. I don't see executable as a valid stream type. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams. *The security people at MS would go spastic if this was allowed*.

Comment: Programmers handle this situation by having a switch on the command line.